# SQL Server Deadlocking Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for the proper way to prevent a deadlocking issues being caused by multiple processes trying to update the same record in a table. I've been able to prevent the deadlocks by first selecting the record `WITH (UPDLOCK)` then doing the update. However, I'm not sure if this will work all the time or if it will cause other blocking issues when other processes are inserting new records or updating other records in this table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ReduceOrderAmount
           @OrderId         INT,
           @ReductionAmount INT
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @dDateTime AS DATETIME                  
SET @dDateTime = GETUTCDATE()

BEGIN TRANSACTION

--Quick Fix... Attempt to block other callers who are trying to update the same record. 
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE ORDER_ID = @OrderId

UPDATE dbo.ORDERS
SET QTY_OPEN = QTY_OPEN - @ReductionAmount,
UPDATED_WHEN = @dDateTime
WHERE ORDER_ID = @OrderId           

COMMIT

END
```

Comment: A deadlock usually involves at least 2 resources (tables). Do you have an error message/scenario?

Comment: why do you have the select into the transaction? why don't you have it outside the transaction ?

Comment: you can also add with (updlock) to an update command

Comment: Is it possible that the application code that uses this sproc initiates a distributed transaction? In which case other operations in the distributed transaction cause the deadlock, not what happens in this sproc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't understand why do you have your select query inside the transction. You're not using it in the update query, so I think you can put it outside.

Then, maybe you could try to [change your Isolation Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL
    { READ UNCOMMITTED
    | READ COMMITTED
    | REPEATABLE READ
    | SNAPSHOT
    | SERIALIZABLE
    }
[ ; ]
```

Might try one of this

> READ UNCOMMITTED Specifies that statements can read rows that have
>   been modified by other transactions but not yet committed.
>
> REPEATABLE READ Specifies that statements cannot read data that has
>   been modified but not yet committed by other transactions and that no
>   other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current
>   transaction until the current transaction completes.
>
> SNAPSHOT Specifies that data read by any statement in a transaction
>   will be the transactionally consistent version of the data that
>   existed at the start of the transaction. The transaction can only
>   recognize data modifications that were committed before the start of
>   the transaction. Data modifications made by other transactions after
>   the start of the current transaction are not visible to statements
>   executing in the current transaction. The effect is as if the
>   statements in a transaction get a snapshot of the committed data as it
>   existed at the start of the transaction.
>
> SERIALIZABLE Specifies the following: Statements cannot read data that
>   has been modified but not yet committed by other transactions. No
>   other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current
>   transaction until the current transaction completes. Other
>   transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would fall in
>   the range of keys read by any statements in the current transaction
>   until the current transaction completes.